# getter setter with Property wrappers

Tags: swift

I am trying to wrap (pun intended) my head around Property wrappers. While as a concept and value it brings is quite clear to me, I am getting confused as to why I cannot use getter (setter) in the code below:

My code:

```
    @propertyWrapper struct Capitalized {
        var wrappedValue: String {
           get {
          return wrappedValue.capitalized 
            }
        }
        
        init(wrappedValue: String) {
            self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue.capitalized  
//error: Cannot assign to property: 'wrappedValue' is a get-only property
        }
    }
```

Code from tutorial which actually works:

```
 @propertyWrapper struct Capitalized {
        var wrappedValue: String {
            didSet { wrappedValue = wrappedValue.capitalized }
        }
    
        init(wrappedValue: String) {
            self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue.capitalized
        }
    }
 
struct User {
        @Capitalized var firstName: String
        @Capitalized var lastName: String
    }   
    
    // John Appleseed
        var user = User(firstName: "john", lastName: "appleseed")
        
    // John Smith
        user.lastName = "smith"
```

As per my understanding of computed properties, I am capitalising wrapped value and returning it, not sure why I am getting the error which is highlighting the exact same thing!

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the `wrappedValue` property as get-only when you define it as a computed property as you've done in the code. Also, this causes an infinite loop when the getter is trying the get the value of its own.

```
var wrappedValue: String {
    get { wrappedValue.capitalized }
}
```

The fix is to use the `didSet` method.

```
var wrappedValue: String {
    didSet { wrappedValue = wrappedValue.capitalized }
}
```

Comment: infinite loop as in? am sorry didn't quite understand that?

Comment: The getter block is calling the property which in turn calls the properties getter this causes an infinite loop.